# Calendar to show U.S. holidays while scheduling event

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, coldfusion

My client schedules appointments for her customers often many months in advanced.  If the booking occurs during a US Holiday day/week, my client would like to be notified that the schedule date falls during a US holiday (she charges more for her services on holidays).

*My client is only concerned with the following dates:*

- New Years Dec.30-Jan.2
- Spring Break Week in March (3rd week in March)
- Easter Weekend (this date varies each year)
- Memorial Day Weekend in May
- Independence Day Weekend in July
- Labor Day Weekend in September
- Thanksgiving Week Monday-Sunday in November
- Christmas Week December 22-28

I'd like to automate this as much as possible so she doesn't have to update the database each year but that is not her requirement but rather mine. :D  Would it be best to input the holiday dates/rules into the database or use a rules to determine if the date of the appointment falls on or within a holiday day/week when the appointment is being scheduled?

If database is the answer, I'll need some help with the database design and how to setup the recurrence of the events.  If rule based, I'll need some help with that, too (e.g. determining when is Spring Break, Easter, etc.).

I'm using MSSQL 2005 (might be moving to mssql 2008 very soon) and ColdFusion 9.

TIA

Comment: I left Matt Busche as the selected answer but I did provide my own answer based off of his solution (I wanted him to get credit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [wrote a UDF](http://matthewbusche.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/26/get-US-Bank-Holidays-UDF) last month to help with many US Holidays, but it doesn't cover all. This should give you a decent start.

You can also use this [UDF from CFLib](http://cflib.org/udf/getBankHolidays) that will get you Easter day

Once you have Memorial Day you can do a simple `dateadd()` and take away 1 and 2 days to get the full weekend.

```
<cffunction name="getUSBankHolidays" access="public" output="false" returntype="struct" hint="general bank holidays for US">
  <cfargument name="iYear" default="#Year(now())#" />

    <cfset var currentYear = arguments.iYear />

    <!--- Static dates per year --->
    <cfset var strResult = 
      { NewYears1      = createDate(currentYear,12,30),
        NewYears2      = createDate(currentYear,12,31),
        NewYears3      = createDate(currentYear,1,1),
        NewYears4      = createDate(currentYear,1,2),
        Independence   = createDate(currentYear,7,4),
        Christmas1     = createDate(currentYear,12,22),
        Christmas2     = createDate(currentYear,12,23),
        Christmas3     = createDate(currentYear,12,24),
        Christmas4     = createDate(currentYear,12,25),
        Christmas5     = createDate(currentYear,12,26),
        Christmas6     = createDate(currentYear,12,27),
        Christmas7     = createDate(currentYear,12,28)
  } />

    <cfset strResult.SpringBreak          = createDate(currentYear,3,GetNthOccOfDayInMonth(3,1,3,currentYear)) />
    <cfset strResult.MemorialDay          = createDate(currentYear,5,(DaysInMonth(createDate(2012,5,1))) - (DayOfWeek(createDate(2012,5,DaysInMonth(createDate(2012,5,1)))) - 2)) />
    <cfset strResult.LaborDay             = createDate(currentYear,9,GetNthOccOfDayInMonth(1,2,9,currentYear)) />
    <cfset strResult.Thanksgiving         = createDate(currentYear,11,GetNthOccOfDayInMonth(4,6,11,currentYear)) />

    <cfreturn strResult />
</cffunction>

<cfdump var="#getUSBankHolidays()#">

<!-- This code will tell you if the date is holiday or not --->
<cfset Today = '2012-01-01' />
<cfdump var="#NOT arrayIsEmpty(structFindValue(getUSBankHolidays(),createDate(year(Today),month(Today),day(Today))))#">
```

You will also need [this UDF](http://cflib.org/udf/GetLastOccOfDayInMonth) from CFLib.org to get the nth occurence of a day in a month.

Comment: Mission Accomplished.  Thanks again.

Comment: While excellent, this doesn't account for holidays which fall on a weekend and thus, for time off purposes, are observed a day early or a day later. (For instance, when July 4 is a Saturday, everybody that gets Independence Day off (usually) gets July 3 off instead.)

Answer (score 1):

A database table will give you a lot more flexibility.

The data warehouse I help maintain has a table called period which has the date for the primary key.  Other fields include holiday, some fiscal year stuff, and some other fields that are important to us.  Other tables have foreign key references to table.

In addition to enabling us to easily generate our necessary reports, this table also allows us to use left joins to identify dates where something didn't happen.  Something like that might be useful in your situation.

As far as updating goes, we do it manually.  When something like Christmas falls on a weekend, we wait to be told whether we get Friday or Monday off.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I would put it in code.  I found this a few years back and have used it per its license agreement.  It is Java Based but I am sure you could change to Coldfusion if you needed to.  It currently has code for 66 holidays listed and sure you could manipulate it some to calculate the week that you need.

http://mindprod.com/applet/holidays.html

http://mindprod.com/precis/holidays.txt

https://wush.net/websvn/mindprod/listing.php?repname=mindprod&path=%2Fcom%2Fmindprod%2Fholidays%2F

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using and is flexible enough to modify in the future and I might still convert this to a database driven system complete with a GUI to add future dates but for now, this works great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" /> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true 
  }); 
}); 
</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<cfoutput> 
<form action="#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post"> 
  Start Date: <input type="text" name="StartDate" class="datepicker" /> (mm-dd-yyyy)<br /> 
  End Date: <input type="text" name="EndDate" class="datepicker" /> (mm-dd-yyyy) <br /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Save Appointment" /> 
</form> 
<cfif structkeyexists(form,'startDate')> 
<cfdump var="#form#" expand="no"> 
<hr /> 
<cfscript> 
/** 
* Returns the day of the month(1-31) of an Nth Occurrence of a day (1-sunday,2-monday etc.)in a given month. * 
* @param NthOccurrence      A number representing the nth occurrence.1-5. 
* @param TheDayOfWeek      A number representing the day of the week (1=Sunday, 2=Monday, etc.). 
* @param TheMonth      A number representing the Month (1=January, 2=February, etc.). 
* @param TheYear      The year. 
* @return Returns a numeric value. 
* @author Ken McCafferty (mccjdk@yahoo.com) 
* @version 1, August 28, 2001 
*/
function GetNthOccOfDayInMonth(NthOccurrence,TheDayOfWeek,TheMonth,TheYear) 
{
  Var TheDayInMonth=0; 
  if(TheDayOfWeek lt DayOfWeek(CreateDate(TheYear,TheMonth,1))){ 
    TheDayInMonth= 1 + NthOccurrence*7  + (TheDayOfWeek - DayOfWeek(CreateDate(TheYear,TheMonth,1))) MOD 7; 
  } 
  else { 
    TheDayInMonth= 1 + (NthOccurrence-1)*7  + (TheDayOfWeek - DayOfWeek(CreateDate(TheYear,TheMonth,1))) MOD 7; 
  } 
  //If the result is greater than days in month or less than 1, return -1
  if(TheDayInMonth gt DaysInMonth(CreateDate(TheYear,TheMonth,1)) OR   TheDayInMonth lt 1){ 
    return -1; 
  } 
  else { 
    return TheDayInMonth; 
  } 
} 
/** 
* Returns the date for Easter in a given year.
* Minor edits by Rob Brooks-Bilson (rbils@amkor.com).
* 
* @param TheYear      The year to get Easter for. 
* @return Returns a date object. 
* @author Ken McCafferty (rbils@amkor.commccjdk@yahoo.com) 
* @version 1, September 4, 2001 
*/
function GetEaster() {
  Var TheYear=iif(arraylen(arguments) gt 0,"arguments[1]", "Year(Now())"); 
  Var century = Int(TheYear/100);
  Var G = TheYear MOD 19;
  Var K = Int((century - 17)/25);
  Var I = (century - Int(century/4) - Int((century - K)/3) + 19*G + 15) MOD 30;
  Var H = I - Int((I/28))*(1 - Int((I/28))*Int((29/(I + 1)))*Int(((21 - G)/11)));
  Var J = (TheYear + Int(TheYear/4) + H + 2 - century + Int(century/4)) MOD 7;
  Var L = H - J;
  Var EasterMonth = 3 + Int((L + 40)/44);
  Var EasterDay = L + 28 - 31*Int((EasterMonth/4));
  return CreateDate(TheYear,EasterMonth,EasterDay);
}

function LastDayOfMonth(strMonth) {
  var strYear=Year(Now());
  if (ArrayLen(Arguments) gt 1)
    strYear=Arguments[2];
  return DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 1, CreateDate(strYear, strMonth, 1))); 
}
</cfscript>

<cfset StartYear = listlast(StartDate,'/')>
<cfset EndYear = listlast(endDate,'/')>
<cfset HolidaySchedule = structnew()>
<cfloop index="currentYear" from="#dateformat(StartDate,'yyyy')#" to="#dateformat(EndDate,'yyyy')#" step="1"> 
<cfset val = StructInsert( HolidaySchedule, "Independence (#currentYear#)", createDate(currentYear,7,4) )/> 
<cfset val = StructInsert( HolidaySchedule, "New Year (#currentYear#)", createdate(currentYear,1,1) )/> 
<cfset val = StructInsert( HolidaySchedule, "Easter (#currentYear#)", GetEaster(currentYear) )/> 
<cfset val = StructInsert( HolidaySchedule, "Spring Break (#currentYear#)", createDate(currentYear,3,GetNthOccOfDayInMonth(2,2,3,currentYear)) )/>
<cfset val = StructInsert( HolidaySchedule, "Labor Day (#currentYear#)", createDate(currentYear,9,GetNthOccOfDayInMonth(1,2,9,currentYear)) )/>
<cfset val = StructInsert( HolidaySchedule, "Thanksgiving (#currentYear#)", createDate(currentYear,11,GetNthOccOfDayInMonth(4,6,11,currentYear)) )/>
<cfset val = StructInsert( HolidaySchedule, "Christmas Day (#currentYear#)", createdate(currentYear,12,25) )/>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#HolidaySchedule#" expand="no">
<cfset normalweek = 'true'>
<cfloop index="x" from="#startDate#" to="#endDate#" step="1">
Checking date: #dateformat(x,'yyyy-mm-dd')#<br />
<cfif NOT arrayIsEmpty(structFindValue(HolidaySchedule,createDate(year(x),month(x),day(x))))> 
<div style="background-color:##009900; color:##ffffff">#dateformat(x, 'mm/dd/yyyy')# is a holiday.</div> 
<cfset normalweek = 'false'>
</cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfif normalweek eq 'false'>
Remember to add on the Holiday Fee.
<cfelse>
No additional charges for this appointment.
</cfif>
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```